# How to pass the provisioning profile name in xcodebuild command?

Tags: ios, jenkins, xcodebuild, xcode-plugin

I want to fully automize the build option to generate archive and iPA through command line tools i.e xcodebuild.

Problem facing :- I am generating the archive using 
xcodebuild -schme XYZ -archivePath .../XYZ.xcarchive archive.

Question :- The archive generated/signed via developer account whereas  release is selected from Edit scheme.

Comment: I dont understand your question. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to the archive file with below command.

```
xcodebuild archive -project <PROJECT_NAME>.xcodeproj -scheme <NAME_OF_SCHEME> -archivePath <PROJECT_NAME>.xcarchive
```

And then you need to export the archive into an ipa.

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath <PROJECT_NAME>.xcarchive -exportPath <PROJECT_NAME> -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile "Name of Provisioning Profile"
```

However I am not sure this is what you are looking for.